# Dynamic SQL + UNION ALL - repeat the same statement for all cells of a single column

Tags: sql, t-sql, union, dynamic-sql, union-all

I'd like to combine multiple result-sets of *i* (i=1,...,n) SELECT statements using UNION ALL. Example:

```
select person_id, brand
from anydatabase
where brand = 'A'

union all

select person_id, brand
from anydatabase
where brand = 'B'
```

...

I'd like to repeat the SELECT statements shown above for all i brands that are part of a single column in my brand_database. Since my brand_database contains many brands, I'd highly appreciate some kind of automatization.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
superdell

Comment: If this is a common query, it sounds like your brands should be in a table, and SELECT person_id, brand FROM anydatabase ad JOIN Brand b ON ad.BradnId = b.Id GROUP BY b.brand. If not, and moving them to a table is too large of an ask, combine the group by with an IN statement, or if you want ALL brands, exclude the IN statement.

Comment: Do you really mean you want a result including all brands? Why not simply `select person_id, brand
from anydatabase
where brand is not null`?

Comment: @scaisEdge pointed out a mistake in my initial assessment. You DON'T want GROUP BY, you want ORDER BY. Everything else holds.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply using a IN clause

```
select distinct person_id, brand
from anydatabase
where brand IN ( 'A', 'B', .....,'Z')
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a group by, to preserve the grouping functionality of a union.

Comment: @dylanthelion, which grouping functionality?

Comment: @dylanthelion   thanks  ..but UNION ALL select all the rows ,,, for distinct result yu need  UNION and for this you can use DISTINCT (not group by)

Comment: @scaisEdge: Accurate, and sorry. I was confused by all of the distinct in the answers. In that case, I would suggest ORDER BY brand. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using a subquery in IN Clause

```
select person_id, brand
from anydatabase
where brand in (select distinct brand from anydatabase)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers but unfortunately you got me completely wrong :D

Since my problem above is just part of a much larger query, I will reconsider my idea and try to explain my problem in a more detailed way and return to stackoverflow.

so far - superdell